# printing in WPF - making your own 'bill' - any directions?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, datagrid

I am wondering the best way to make bills, or reports or anything printing related in WPF. I am thinking of using iTextSharp but I wanna see what other ways are there. Can anyone here direct me in the right way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding for POS(Point Of Sale) System, then you can use System.Drawing.Printing Library for printing bill, which is really fast.
For reports, use crystal reports for dynamic pdf reports generation because you can export it to pdf, excel and rpt.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenXML SDK is Microsoft's own library for working with Office (> 2007) documents: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425 . It's reasonably straightforward to use, and comes with the handy 'OpenXMLSDKTool' which takes existing Office files and creates the source code required to generate them.